# Lotus Notes : Run agent to send mail from app

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am designing a application that will send notification email to mail addressee.
There is a field in the application named 'RemindDate'.
If `RemindDate=Today` then send mail to mail address which I will key in later.

What I have done is this;

I selected `agent type = formula`, and run it daily.

In the Agent's Document selection, I selected `Condition>By form` and chose a form which the filed is located at.

In the Agent's Action, I wrote;

```
SELECT @All;
@If(@Date(@Now)=@Date(RemindDate);@MailSend(Name;"";"";"TEST ";"";"";[IncludeDoclink]);"")
```

But unfortunately, until now I still did not get any notification mail.

Kindly assist.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does the agent log say? Click right on agent in Domino Designer and choose "View Log".

Comment: The agent log stated:

Started running agent 'Agent name' on [today' date and time].
Running on all documents in database: 177 total.
Found 177 documents that match search criteria
177 documents were modified by formula
Done running agent 'Agent name' on [today's date and time].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set agent's target option "All documents in database" in addition:

[image]

With the default target option "All new & modified documents" it would run the code only once for a document. But, you want to test for field "RemindDate" for every document every day. So, target option "All documents in database" is needed here.

*Update*

Flag "[IncludeDocLink]" does only work if the database has a **default view**.

Set this option to one view.

[image]

This is an optimized version of your formula code:

```
SELECT RemindDate != "" & @Today = @Date(RemindDate);
@MailSend(Name;""; ""; "TEST"; ""; ""; [INCLUDEDOCLINK])
```

Comment: @KnutHermann Thanks for your reply.
Actually I have initially set the target to All documents in database. But still the same output.
Thank you.

Comment: Also, test that you actually have documents when the agent runs (i.e., don't assume that just because the agent is running there actually are new documents.)  Agent Manager runs agents at midnight whether they need it or not.